# NULL Pointer exception at Cucumber StepDifinition

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

I am using Cucumber BDD with TestNG , however getting NullPointerException at my step.

I have tried many thing suggested here but no use.

Please help me.I am really not sure what is causing the error

**Runner file which is a BasePage:**

```
package main;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.SimpleTimeZone;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.common.io.Files;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
//import helpers.ReportHelper;
import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import ptest.utilities.ExtentTestManager;
import ptest.utilities.ReadExcel;

@CucumberOptions(strict = true, 
                monochrome = true, 
                features = "src/test/resources/features", 
                glue = "stepdefinition", 
                //format = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"}, 
                tags = { "@TC001" }
                        )

public class CucumberRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    public static Properties prop;
    public  static EventFiringWebDriver e_driver;
    public static WebElement webelement;
    public static List<WebElement> webelements = null;
    public static int defaultBrowserTimeOut = 30000;
    public static List<String> windowHandlers;
    public static ReadExcel readExcel;



    public static WebDriver GoToURL(String browserName, String url)throws UnknownHostException {

        //deleteTempFile();

        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\geckodriver.exe");
            /*  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);*/
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(url);
        } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("iexplorer")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            /*  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.

            capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
            capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);*/
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");               
            driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
            driver.get(url);
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(defaultBrowserTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("iexplorer"))
            SwitchToAlert();

        if (windowHandlers == null)
            windowHandlers = new LinkedList<String>();
        else
            windowHandlers.clear();

        windowHandlers.add(driver.getWindowHandle());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;

    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
    /*  
     * @AfterMethod public static void shutDownDriver() { if (driver != null)
     * driver.quit(); }
     */



    /**

     * @param driver
     * @param element
     */
    public static void highlightElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                element, "border: 2px solid DeepPink;");
    }


    /**

     * @param locator in particular format mentioned
     * @return WebElement
     */
    public static WebElement findElement(String locator) {

        //Locator Values are Expected in string format like "name==abc" or "id==pqr" or "xpath==//*[@id='uname']"

        if (locator != null) {
            String[] arrLocator = locator.split("==");
            String locatorTag = arrLocator[0].trim();
            String objectLocator = arrLocator[1].trim();
            try {
                if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                    webelement = driver.findElement(By.id(objectLocator));
                    //highlightElement(driver, webelement);
                } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                    webelement = driver.findElement(By.name(objectLocator));
                    //highlightElement(driver, webelement);
                } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
                    webelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectLocator));
                    //highlightElement(driver, webelement);
                } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("linkText")) {
                    webelement = driver.findElement(By.linkText(objectLocator));
                    //highlightElement(driver, webelement);
                } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("class")) {
                    webelement = driver
                            .findElement(By.className(objectLocator));
                    //highlightElement(driver, webelement);
                } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("css")) {
                    webelement = driver.findElement(By
                            .cssSelector(objectLocator));
                    //highlightElement(driver, webelement);
                } else {
                    String error = "Please Check the Given Locator Syntax :"
                            + locator;
                    error = error.replaceAll("'", "\"");

                    return null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Failure Reason:- "+e.getMessage());
                Assert.assertTrue(false);
                String error = "Please Check the Given Locator Syntax :"
                        + locator;
                error = error.replaceAll("'", "\"");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;                

            }
        }

        return webelement;
    }




    //Click Method
    public void click(By elementLocation) {
        waitVisibility(elementLocation);
        driver.findElement(elementLocation).click();
    }

    //Write Text
    public void writeText(By elementLocation, String text) {
        waitVisibility(elementLocation);
        driver.findElement(elementLocation).sendKeys(text);
    }

    //Read Text
    public String readText(By elementLocation) {
        waitVisibility(elementLocation);
        return driver.findElement(elementLocation).getText();
    }

    //Wait
    public void waitVisibility(By by){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));      
    }
    public WebElement findByClassName(String ClassName) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className(ClassName));

        return element;
    }




    /**
     * Find WebElement By CssSelector.
     *
     * @param CssSelector
     * @return Return Web Element.
     */
    public WebElement findByCssSelector(String CssSelector) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CssSelector));

        return element;
    }

    /**

     * @param locator
     * desc Whether the checkbox is checked or not 
     */
    public static boolean isCheckboxChecked(String locator) {
        WebElement element = findElement(locator);
        if (element.isSelected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**

     * * @param locator
     * @return list of webelement found
     */
    public static List<WebElement> findElements(String locator) {

        if (locator != null) {
            String[] arrLocator = locator.split("==");
            String locatorTag = arrLocator[0].trim();
            String objectLocator = arrLocator[1].trim();

            if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                webelements = driver.findElements(By.id(objectLocator));
            } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                webelements = driver.findElements(By.name(objectLocator));
            } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
                webelements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(objectLocator));
            } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("linkText")) {
                webelements = driver.findElements(By.linkText(objectLocator));
            } else if (locatorTag.equalsIgnoreCase("class")) {
                webelements = driver.findElements(By.className(objectLocator));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please Check the Locator Syntax Given :"
                        + locator);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return webelements;
    }

    /**

     * @param locator
     * desc Check a Checkbox having a particular value as its attribute 
     */
    public static void CheckCheckBox(String Locator, String Value)
    {
        List<WebElement> oCheckBox = findElements(Locator);


        // This will tell you the number of checkboxes are present

        int iSize = oCheckBox.size();

        // Start the loop from first checkbox to last checkbox

        for(int i=0; i < iSize ; i++ ){

            // Store the checkbox name to the string variable, using 'Value' attribute

            String sValue = oCheckBox.get(i).getAttribute("value");

            // Select the checkbox it the value of the checkbox is same what you are looking for

            if (sValue.equalsIgnoreCase(Value))
            {

                oCheckBox.get(i).click();

                // This will take the execution out of for loop

                break;

            }

        }
    }


    /**
     * ram ID
     * <p>
     * Find Web Element By ID.
     *
     * @paturn Return Web Element.
     */
    public WebElement findById(String ID) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(ID));

        return element;
    }

    /**

     * @throws AWTException 
     */
    public static void PressShiftTab() throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(3000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); 
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    }

    /**

     * @throws AWTException 
     */
    public static void PressTab() throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(3000);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); 

    }
    /**

     * @param locator of the Web Element
     * @param attributeName
     * @return attributeValue
     */
    public static String getAttribute(String locator, String attributeName) {
        String attributeValue = null;
        try {

            WebElement element = findElement(locator);
            if (element != null)
                attributeValue = element.getAttribute(attributeName);
            element = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return attributeValue;
    }

    /**

     * @param locator of the Element to be cleared
     */
    public static void clearElement(String locator) {
        try {

            WebElement element = findElement(locator);
            element.clear();
            element = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    /**

     * @param locator
     * @param value
     */
    public static void enterText(String locator, String value) {

        try {

            WebElement element = findElement(locator);
            element.sendKeys(value);
            element = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**

     * @param locator of Element to be clicked
     * @return 
     */
    public static  void click(String locator) {
        try {
            WebElement element = findElement(locator);
            if (element != null)
                element.click();
            else
                System.out.println("Element Is NULL");
            element = null;     
            /*Assert.assertTrue(false);*/

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(" Error occured whlie click on the element "
                    + locator + " *** " + e.getMessage());
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Failure Reason:- "+e.getMessage());
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
    }

    /**

     * @param locator
     * @return Text/value of the Element
     */
    public static String getElementText(String locator) {
        WebElement element;
        String text = null;
        try {
            element = findElement(locator);
            if (element != null)

                text = element.getText();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Failure Reason:- "+e.getMessage());
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
        element = null;

        return text;
    }

    /**

     * @param propertyType
     * @param propertyValue
     */
    public static void mouseHover(String locator) {

        WebElement mouseOverElement = findElement(locator);
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  // Configure the Action    
        Action mouseOver =builder.moveToElement(mouseOverElement).build(); // Get the action    
        mouseOver.perform(); // Execute the Action 
    }

    /**
     * Find Web Element By findByLinkText.
     *
     * @param linkText
     * @return Return Web Element.
     */
    public WebElement findByLinkText(String linkText) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText));

        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Find Web Element By Name.
     *
     * @param Name
     * @return Return Web Element.
     */
    public WebElement findByName(String Name) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(Name));

        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Find Web Element By Partial_Link_Text.
     *
     * @param PartialLinkText
     * @return Return Web Element.
     */
    public WebElement findByPartialLinkText(String PartialLinkText) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(PartialLinkText));

        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Find Web Element By Tag_Name.
     *
     * @param TagName
     * @return Return Web Element.
     */
    public WebElement findByTagName(String TagName) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName(TagName));

        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Find Web Element By findByXpath.
     *
     * @param XpathExpression
     * @return Return Web Element.
     */
    public WebElement findByXpath(String XpathExpression) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(XpathExpression));

        return element;
    }










}
```

**Step Definition:**

```
package stepdefinition;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestContext;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import main.CucumberRunner;
import pages.CuraLoginPage;

public class LoginStep extends CucumberRunner {

    CuraLoginPage curaloginpage;



    @Given("^User logged in with \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"$")
    public void user_login(String logicalName,String url) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println(logicalName);
        System.out.println(url);

          Method method; ITestContext iTestContext;
        try {
            curaloginpage.LogintoCura(logicalName, url); **>>> NULL POINTER EXCEPTION**
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stepdefinition.LoginStep.user_login(LoginStep.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:27)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:27)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:49)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:67)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:124)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:28)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help as I am trying cucumber with TestNG for the first time.
I am not using driver in the step definition. I am really not sure what is causing the NullPointerException to occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not created the instance of the CuraLoginPage in the step definition. If you are using the TestNG page object model then you need to add something like below.

```
CuraLoginPage curaloginpage;

public LoginStep()
{
    curaloginpage = new CuraLoginPage(driver);
}
```

If possible then share the code of code of CuraLoginPage too.

Comment: Hello , it worked , also I am pasting CuraLoginPage code below. Dont know why but I am getting NULL POINTER at sendkeys while entering username . I am getting all the data required and object xpath is correct too.

Comment: If this worked then please mark this as accepted. I will definitely help you with your other issues too. :)

Comment: In the constructor, you haven't called PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);

Comment: public CuraLoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }

Comment: Hello , no brother it did not work , same error
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:70)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:39)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
 at pages.CuraLoginPage.LogintoCura(CuraLoginPage.java:70)
 at stepdefinition.LoginStep.user_login(LoginStep.java:29)

Comment: I believe that Webdriver is null.